# How do I get browser timezone using Flex/AS3?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, timezone

How do I get client browser's timezone in Flex/AS3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look on the following: http://thanksmister.com/2011/10/06/determining-local-timezone-in-actionscript-air-flex-as3/

It may help.

Comment: The link is dead...:(

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the [timeZoneOffest](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#timezoneOffset) of the Date object?

Honestly, I believe this just passes back information based on the user's OS settings.  I wouldn't have expected a bBrowser to actually have a time zone.

Comment: Yes I can use timeZoneOffset. However I am looking for some feature/library which allows to show GMT-5 as EST etc.

Comment: @Satish So you're looking for a way to format the data?  That is not obvious from your original question.

Comment: Yes exactly for formatting the date to show timezone info in it. I am looking for AS3 library where I can render GMT-5 as EST and so-on

Comment: @Satish them either modify the original question, or post a new one.  This question has nothing to do with ways to 'render' or format the data.

Comment: That's not quite true.  GMT-0500 is not the same as EST.  GMT+/-[HHMM] is a specified offset of GMT, which is a poor way to represent a users Time Zone, since EST can be GMT-0400 or GMT-0500 depending on Daylight Savings. 

The question is still valid, how do you get the configured OS Time Zone, not the *current* offset, which is only helpful but not the whole story.

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure what exactly you're responding too; and which portion of the question, answer, or comment thread is not quite true.

Answer (score 1):

I've been wanting the same thing, but I found nothing on the Internet. I was already using [FlexDateUtils](http://code.google.com/p/flexdateutils/) ([blog post](http://flexoop.com/2008/12/flex-date-utils-date-and-time-format-part-ii/)), but it only formats timezones as 'GMT -600'. Luckily, I can safely say that the users of my app will be in the United States, so I modified to 'DateUtils.buildTimeZoneDesignation(date:Date)' as follows. I hope this helps.

```
    private static function buildTimeZoneDesignation( date:Date ):String {
        if ( !date ) {
            return "";
        }
        var timezoneOffsetHours:Number = date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;

        // custom timezone handlers (assumes major U.S. zones with daylight savings time dates as of 2011)
        if (3 < timezoneOffsetHours && timezoneOffsetHours < 12)
        {
            var usDST:Boolean = false;
            // the date of the Sunday before today unless today is Sunday
            var sundayBeforeToday:Number = date.date - date.day;
            if (2007 <= date.fullYear) {
                // test for since-2007 extended daylight savings time
                if (2 < date.month && date.month < 10) {
                    // daylight savings time (April through October)
                    usDST = true;
                }
                else if (date.month == 2) {
                    // DST starts second Sunday in March
                    usDST = (7 < sundayBeforeToday);
                }
                else if (date.month == 10) {
                    // DST ends first Sunday in November
                    usDST = (0 < sundayBeforeToday);
                }
            }
            else {
                // test for pre-2007 daylight savings time
                if (3 < date.month && date.month < 9) {
                    // daylight savings time (May through September)
                    usDST = true;
                }
                else if (date.month == 3) {
                    // DST starts first Sunday in April
                    usDST = (0 < sundayBeforeToday);
                }
                else if (date.month == 9) {
                    // DST ends last Sunday in October
                    usDST = (sundayBeforeToday + 7 <= 31);
                }
            }
            // return custom timezone strings for US timezones
            switch (timezoneOffsetHours) {
                case 4:
                    // Eastern or Atlantic
                    return usDST ? "EDT" : "AST";
                case 5:
                    // Central or Eastern
                    return usDST ? "CDT" : "EST";
                case 6:
                    // Mountain or Central
                    return usDST ? "MDT" : "CST";
                case 7:
                    // Pacific or Mountain
                    return usDST ? "PDT" : "MST";
                case 8:
                    // Alaska or Pacific
                    return usDST ? "AKDT" : "PST";
                case 9:
                    // Hawaii or Alaska
                    return usDST ? "HADT" : "AKST";
                case 10:
                    // Samoa or Hawaii
                    return usDST ? "SDT" : "HAST";
                case 11:
                    if (!usDST)
                        // Samoa
                        return "SST";
                    break;
            }
        }

        // else just generate a GMT string

        var timeZoneAsString:String = "GMT ";
        // timezoneoffset is the number that needs to be added to the local time to get to GMT, so
        // a positive number would actually be GMT -X hours
        if ( 0 < timezoneOffsetHours && timezoneOffsetHours < 10 ) {
            timeZoneAsString += "-0" + ( timezoneOffsetHours ).toString();
        } else if ( date.getTimezoneOffset() < 0 && timezoneOffsetHours > -10 ) {
            timeZoneAsString += "0" + ( -1 * timezoneOffsetHours ).toString();
        }
        // add zeros to match standard format
        timeZoneAsString += "00";

        return timeZoneAsString;
    }
```